# Проигрывать видео с всплывающем окне

Tags: android

Сделал простое приложение электронного меню с фотографиями и описанием каждого блюда. При клике на фотографию блюда должно проигрываться видео в всплывающем окне. За неимением знаний моё приложение открывает новое Activity и уже там воспроизводит видео.

Мой код:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class SalatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_salat);
        VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView4);
        String videoPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.tuna;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    }
}
```

Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Вам нужно из adapter передать id выбранного продукта (или весь продукт) в Activity, а уже из Activity передать этот id (или весь продукт) в Dialog, BottomSheet или Fragment. А в них уже воспроизводите видео

Comment: Если вам не трудно вы не могли бы помочь буду признателен. Рассказав по подробнее так как начал изучать не так давно много не ясностей